# PHP Session or Cookie after Refreshing a Page

Tags: php, session, cookies, refresh

I'm a beginner at PHP and I can't seem to find an answer to my question regarding sessions or cookies after refreshing a page.

What I want is to store a boolean value on a variable in PHP - true if it is the first load of the page and false if it is not (e.g. it is the load after a refresh or something like that).

Can you help me with this? Thank you.

---

```
$forAnimation;

if(isset($_COOKIE["pollChart"])){
    $forAnimation = false;
} else {
    setcookie("pollChart");
    $forAnimation = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated the code snippet where I tried using cookies.

Comment: As shown in manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), you should have a key and value on the `setcookie`. `$forAnimation = true; setcookie("pollChart",$forAnimation);` Now you should have `$_COOKIE['pollChart']` set as `true`.

Comment: It still returns the same value for both the first load and after the page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are pretty straight-forward, you just set a key, value, expiration time, etc. You can look at how it works in the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

```
// If the cookie is not set
if(!isset($_COOKIE["pollChart"])){
    // Set cookie key and string value
    setcookie("pollChart",json_encode(array('set'=>false)));
// If set already, change value
} else {
    // Decode array
    $dec    =   json_decode($_COOKIE['pollChart'],true);
    // If the set value is true
    if($dec['set'])
        // Expire the cookie
        setcookie("pollChart",'',(time()-3600));
    // If set to false turn it to true
    else
        setcookie("pollChart",json_encode(array('set'=>true)));
}

// Get the contents of the cookies set
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

**Gives you at first-load:**

```
Array
(
    [PHPSESSID] => 4c4871ac239cec6fa2f3f43bcbed6d81
    [pollChart] => {"set":false}
)
```

**Second load:**

```
Array
(
    [PHPSESSID] => 4c4871ac239cec6fa2f3f43bcbed6d81
    [pollChart] => {"set":true}
)
```

**Last load:**

```
Array
(
    [PHPSESSID] => 4c4871ac239cec6fa2f3f43bcbed6d81
)
```